# Change E-Mail Verification to SMS Verification UserCake

Tags: php, web, usercake

I'm currently using [User Cake](http://usercake.com/) to manage users. But I would like to remove E-Mail Verification and add SMS verification options, using SMS Gateways. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

At this stage in development I don't mind using something other then User Cake so please feel free to make a suggestion.